# Please update comment rate limiting text to include all things it rate limits so users stop thinking it's a bug

Tags: bug, comments, rate-limiting, error-message

Lots of people get confused and post stuff like this:

[Comment deletion counts as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179239/comment-deletion-counts-as-a-comment-vote)

Because this text, while validly noting rate-limiting is happening, is *not* validly saying what is being rate-limited:

> You can only submit a comment vote once every 5 seconds.

Excuse my verbose title but this bug is in some sort of weird hellban state, because Jeff `status-bydesign`'ed the "delete vote counts as comment" bug years ago, correctly noting delete votes are rate-limited, and swallowed up the text being incorrect under this.

It's easy to fix.  Change text to "You can only take action on a comment once every 5 seconds."  This should not be closed as duplicate without producing an answer explaining why the text is in fact by design; not the rate limiting.

Comment: Okay, that duplicate is actually correct (I cursorily only picked up the other bug complaints).

Comment: Sure thing, happens to [all of us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178322/152859). :-)